# Why doesn't 'double' store/print more precision values than 'float' in this C program?

Tags: c, floating-point, double, precision

If I run this code:

```
float a=1.123456789;
printf("The float value is %f\n",a);
double b=1.123456789876543
printf("The double value is %lf",b);
```

It prints:

> The float value is 1.123457
>
> The double value is 1.123457

The first line is understandable since the precision of float is ~6 decimal digits. But shouldn't the 2nd line be displaying more digits? I am using Turbo C++ 4.0 for Windows, if that helps.

Comment: OT: Turbo C++ 4.0 is very old, you should switch to a more modern compiler.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to your problem, but when calling a variable argument function like [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), all `float` values will be *promoted* to `double`. That means there's no difference between `"%f"` and `"%lf"` for [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf).

Comment: As for your problem, the previous link to [this `printf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) should be very useful. Read the big table about the `f` format.

Comment: @Osiris, I am getting the same output when I use codeblocks.

Comment: @BundiBedu Yes the reason is explained in the answers, I just wanted to point out that your compiler is rather old and outdated, but this is not the problem in this case.

Comment: FWIW, you may want to try the current *free* (as in *free beer*) [C++Builder Community Edition](https://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder/starter/free-download). It is technically exactly the same as C++Builder Professional, it just has a limited license. **Much** better than Turbo C++ 4.0 and it uses a modern compiler (Clang-based). Actually, any current compiler would be better than TC++4.

Comment: Kindly explain the downvote. There's apparently no way I can know what to improve in the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%f` format specifier prints 6 digits of precision by default.  If you want to print more digits, you need to add a precision to the format specifier:

```
float a=1.123456789;
printf("The float value is %.15f\n",a);
double b=1.123456789876543;
printf("The double value is %.15lf",b);
```

Output:

```
The float value is 1.123456835746765
The double value is 1.123456789876543
```

Comment: So only while *printing* it prints 6 digits, right? Otherwise, internally, double *stores* more digits than float, doesn't it?

Comment: @BundiBedu Correct.  A `double` stores more.

Comment: Also, in your code, after the 6th decimal digit in variable a, it is printing random digits, right? We've supplied only 9 decimal digits and we're asking it to print 15.

Comment: @BundiBedu Not exactly random, but the closest decimal value to the actual binary value stroed.

Answer (score 1):

For the value you see for both the case is same because, in case the precision is omitted, its is taken as 6.

Also, according to default argument promotion, any floating point type, will get promoted to `double` , and that is the requirement for the `%f` conversion specification, too.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1, for `f` format specifier,  (*emphasis mine*)

> The double argument shall be converted to decimal notation in the style "[-]ddd.ddd", where the number of digits after the radix character is equal to the precision specification. **If the precision is missing, it shall be taken as 6**.

If you want more digits after the decimal point (more precision), you need to explicitly mention a value for precision, greater than 6.

Comment: Can you please share a link to the quotation? Is it the C documentation? I am new to C, so it would be helpful.

Comment: @BundiBedu The actual standard is something you have to purchase, but [here is](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) a publicly available draft version which is close enough.